# "Would have" instead of "will have"

Tags: grammar, tenses

In the sentence "I went to the bank to ensure that I would have enough money for my trip," why  is "would have" used instead of "will have"?

"Would have" seems to be conveying the subjunctive mood, but if I went to the bank already, wouldn't I use "will have" to express certainty about having enough money?

Comment: *Would* is not really used in subjunctive situations. “If it **were** any easier, it **wouldn’t be** worth doing.”  As you see, the subjunctive part is in the condition, not in the consequent.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple case of backshifting, since the past tense of *will* is *would*.

### Normal Present

> Today he **says** he ***will* do** it now.
>
> Today I **am going** to the bank to make sure I ***will* have** enough money for my trip.

### Backshifted Past

> Yesterday he **said** he ***would* do** it then.
>
> Yesterday I **went** to the bank to make sure I ***would* have** enough money for my trip.

This is sometimes called “the future in the past”.  It is frequent in reported speech.

Comment: What part of the second sentence licenses the backshifted *would*? I understand the example, "He said he would do it today" as the indirect-speech version of "He said, 'I will do it tomorrow'", so with the backshifted *would*. But I don't think the second sentence is the indirect-speech equivalent of some sentence.

Comment: @MrReality Past #2 can be seen as backshifting Present #2. If *will* means *am going to* here, then *would* means *was going to*. It's the past's future.